# Customized Tailwind css Background Image not displaying upon deployment

Tags: html, background-image, tailwind-css

I have customized Background Image in tailwind.config file and it displays on the local host as expected, however after I deployed the site on Github pages, the background image doesn't display.

Here is the code in the tailwind.config file.

```
   backgroundImage: {
        'heroMobileBg': "url('/public/images/bg-intro-mobile.svg')",
        'heroDesktopBg': "url('/public/images/bg-intro-desktop.svg')",
      },
```

Here is where I used it.

```
 <div class="bg-heroMobileBg bg-no-repeat bg-center bg-cover lg:bg-heroDesktopBg"></div>
```

I tried using the arbitrary values but still couldn't display on deployment. using the dev tools, I could see the background image stated.

```
.bg-heroMobileBg {
    background-image: url(/public/images/bg-intro-mobile.svg);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what am missing, kindly help me.

Comment: Probably there must have been some change in the path of the images. It would be easier to give an accurate answer if you shared the repository.

Comment: @Rohling I thought that was the problem but I have crossed check the paths. Here’s the repo https://github.com/SanMajur/easybank

Comment: In your `tailwind.config.js`, you are setting the path `content: ["./public/**/*.html", "./src/**/*.js"],`. Why are you doing tailwind search for styles in the `public` directory? Shouldn't it be `content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],`? Your html files should be in the `src` folder as well.

Comment: Based on the tutorial I watched on how to setup a tailwind css in a project, the explanation was that src folder should hold the source code of the project(code that shouldn’t be accessible to anyone) and the public folder to hold all the files accessible to the public. Been using that file structure for sometimes now and I have never encounter any issues with the paths. I tried to put all the html files into src folder but it didn’t solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try import in tailwind config file without public
like this:

```
backgroundImage: {
    'heroMobileBg': "url('/public/images/bg-intro-mobile.svg')",
    'heroDesktopBg': "url('/public/images/bg-intro-desktop.svg')",
  },
```

In most cases, you should not include the /public prefix in paths when referencing images in CSS.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I deployed a React Vite app in Vercel. I confirmed that the issue is happening from my side, not from the Vercel by testing a local build.

I guess when building the application `bg-[url('/path/to/image.png')]` is not getting correctly.

So I copied my image into the `assets` folder and created a new utility in my main CSS file.

```
@layer utilities {
  .bg-img {
    background-image: url('assets/background.png');
  }
}
```

Then apply it in the relevant place

```
<div className="bg-img">
```

I could see missing background images after the next deployment.

Answer (score 0):

To access images stored in the `public` directory, always omit `public` when you include it in the path to the image as so:

```
 backgroundImage: {
    'heroMobileBg': "url('/images/bg-intro-mobile.svg')",
    'heroDesktopBg': "url('/images/bg-intro-desktop.svg')",
  },
```

or

```
.bg-heroMobileBg {
    background-image: url(/images/bg-intro-mobile.svg);
}
```